# GCM replies success to server, device not getting message

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing a sample app for iPhone to receive GCM messages. It registers successfully, getting a registration token. Using this token I submit a message to GCM server with it replying success. This has no visible effect on the phone or in the app.
This is true if phone is on, access code entered, both with app running or not running.

What I already checked/tried:

- SenderID, registration token, server auth key are correct. Also tried to reinstall app to get new registration token, problem persists.
- Put trace logs into all callback functions, the ones about registration are called how I expect them to be called, the ones about receiving messages are silent.
- Tried it on wifi and GSM network too, same.
- Attempted to find a solution here on stackoverflow.
- I couldn't check but I am quite confident that there are no ports blocked on wifi.

What can possibly be wrong? Any ideas what else I am to check?

Comment: It doesn't receive the message at all, or just when the device is asleep? Did you register to receive notifications via Apple Push Notification service? The docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1) thoroughly covers what you need to do.

Comment: I don't receive anything. Not even when phone is on and access code entered. Tried with running app and not running app.
I have registered as the link you kindly provided describes.

Comment: Could you add your request to the question. Also did you try setting the priority of the message to high, which should not be done for all messages but for testing purposes it may be helpful.

Comment: Hi,
Yes, I did try to set the priority high.
It would take some time for me to have the request, since I abandoned using GCM and made it work with native Apple APN in 2 hours. *sigh*
However, GCM did reply with success to the request, so it should've been OK.